Watchdog: Change Schedule after start
I'm attempting to write a StackStorm Sensor that leverages Watchdog for its file watching capabilities. There is a builtin sensor, but it doesn't provide the capabilities that I'm looking for. However, I'm running into some confusing thread blocking behavior while attempting to implement the sensor.
I've implemented most of a sensor, but for some reason when starting the WatchDog observer -- which is essentially just a threading.Thread -- the process hangs.
"""StackStorm sensor to to watch for file changes"""

import json
from typing import TypedDict, Callable, Any
from logging import Logger
import re

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.observers.api import BaseObserver
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEvent

import eventlet
from st2reactor.sensor.base import Sensor
import time


class _FileWatchTriggerParams(TypedDict):
    watch_directory: str
    filename_regex: str
    recursive: bool


class _FileWatchTrigger(TypedDict):
    uid: str
    id: str
    ref: str
    name: str
    pack: str
    type: str
    parameters: _FileWatchTriggerParams


class _FileWatcherHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    dispatch_trigger: Callable[[str, Any], None]
    file_regex: re.Pattern | None

    def __init__(
        self,
        dispatch_trigger: Callable[[str, Any], None],
        trigger_ref: str,
        file_regex: str,
        logger: Logger,
    ):
        self.dispatch_trigger = dispatch_trigger
        self.trigger_ref = trigger_ref
        self.logger = logger
        if file_regex and file_regex != ".*":
            self.file_regex = re.compile(file_regex)
        else:
            self.file_regex = None

    def on_any_event(self, event: FileSystemEvent) -> None:
        self.logger.info(
            "%s event occurred on file %s", event.event_type.title(), event.src_path
        )
        if event.is_directory:
            return
        self.logger.info(
            "Trigger %s Evaluating event on file %s", self.trigger_ref, event.src_path
        )
        if self.file_regex is not None:
            if event.dest_path and not self.file_regex.match(event.dest_path):
                return
            if not self.file_regex.match(event.src_path):
                return

        payload = {
            "event_type": event.event_type,
            "src_path": event.src_path,
            "dest_path": event.dest_path,
            "watch_path": self.file_regex,
        }
        self.logger.info(
            "Trigger %s dispatching event %s",
            self.trigger_ref,
            json.dumps(payload, indent=2),
        )
        self.dispatch_trigger(self.trigger_ref, payload)


class FileWatchSensor(Sensor):
    """Sensor allowing for configurable file watchers using the Watchdog library"""

    _logger: Logger
    _reload_needed: bool  # whether the observer needs to be reloaded.
    _triggers: dict[str, _FileWatchTrigger]  # the triggers that are being watched
    _observer: BaseObserver

    def __init__(self, sensor_service, config=None):
        super().__init__(sensor_service=sensor_service, config=config)
        self._logger = self.sensor_service.get_logger(type(self).__qualname__)
        self._reload_needed = False
        self._observer = None
        self._triggers = {}

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self._logger.info("Polling...")
                if self._reload_needed:
                    self.reload_observer()
                eventlet.sleep(1)
                time.sleep(1)
            except Exception:  # pylint: disable=broad-exception-caught
                self._logger.exception(
                    "Unexpected exception while running %s", type(self).__name__
                )

    def cleanup(self):
        if self._observer:
            self._observer.stop()
            self._observer.join()

    def add_trigger(self, trigger: _FileWatchTrigger):
        try:
            self._logger.info(
                "Adding watch on dir [%s] for file [%s]",
                trigger["parameters"].get("watch_directory", "No Watch Directory"),
                trigger["parameters"].get("filename_regex", "No File Pattern"),
            )
            self._triggers[trigger["ref"]] = trigger
            self._reload_needed = True
        except Exception:  # pylint: disable=broad-exception-caught
            self._logger.exception(
                "Unexpected exception while adding trigger: %s",
                json.dumps(trigger, indent=2),
            )

    def update_trigger(self, trigger: _FileWatchTrigger):
        try:
            if trigger["ref"] not in self._triggers:
                self._triggers[trigger["ref"]] = trigger
            else:
                self._triggers[trigger["ref"]].update(trigger)
        except Exception:  # pylint: disable=broad-exception-caught
            self._logger.exception(
                "Unexpected exception while updating trigger: %s",
                json.dumps(trigger, indent=2),
            )

    def remove_trigger(self, trigger: _FileWatchTrigger):
        try:
            if trigger["ref"] in self._triggers:
                removed_trigger = self._triggers.pop(trigger["ref"])
                self._logger.info(
                    "Removing trigger watch %s on dir [%s] for file [%s]",
                    trigger["ref"],
                    removed_trigger["parameters"].get(
                        "watch_directory", "No Watch Directory"
                    ),
                    removed_trigger["parameters"].get("filename_regex", ""),
                )
                self._reload_needed = True
        except Exception:  # pylint: disable=broad-exception-caught
            self._logger.exception(
                "Unexcpected exception while removing trigger: %s",
                json.dumps(trigger, indent=2),
            )

    def reload_observer(self):
        """Build a new observer with the current set of watches"""
        # The observer objects are just threads.
        # Threads can only be started once.
        # Schedules cannot be modified on started threads.
        old_observer = None
        if self._observer:
            old_observer = self._observer
        self._observer = Observer()
        watches = []
        for trigger in self._triggers.values():
            watch_dir = trigger["parameters"].get("watch_directory")
            if not watch_dir:
                self._logger.error(
                    "Trigger missing `watch_directory` parameter: %s for ",
                    json.dumps(trigger, indent=2),
                )
                continue
            pattern = trigger["parameters"].get("filename_regex")
            event_handler = _FileWatcherHandler(
                self.sensor_service.dispatch,
                trigger["ref"],
                pattern,
                self._logger,
            )
            recursive = trigger["parameters"].get("recursive", False)
            self._observer.schedule(
                event_handler,
                watch_dir,
                recursive,
            )
            watches.append(
                (watch_dir, "recursive" if recursive else "standard", pattern or ".*")
            )
        if old_observer is not None:
            self._logger.info("Stopping old observer")
            old_observer.stop()
            old_observer.join()
            self._logger.info("Old observer stopped")
        self._logger.info("Starting observer with %d watches", len(watches))
        self._observer.start()  # Main process gets stuck right here
        self._logger.info("Observer thread started.")
        self._reload_needed = False
        self._logger.info("Watching files: %s", json.dumps(watches, indent=2))


You'll notice there are a lot of log statements around the end of the "reload observer" function -- that's where the issue appears to be.
In implementing this, I discovered that once started, an observer's scheduled watches cannot be modified. Similar to the current state, attempting to do so will block the main thread indefinitely.
I'm running this on StackStorm 3.8.0 using Python 3.11.3
Here are the logs that the sensor generates while attempting to run:
2024-07-31 21:58:51 2024-08-01 02:58:51,369 INFO [-] Sensor ava_core.FileWatchSensor updated. Reloading sensor.
2024-07-31 21:58:52 2024-08-01 02:58:52,387 INFO [-] Sensor ava_core.FileWatchSensor reloaded.
2024-07-31 21:58:53 2024-08-01 02:58:53,200 INFO [-] No config found for sensor "FileWatchSensor"
2024-07-31 21:58:53 2024-08-01 02:58:53,201 INFO [-] Watcher started
2024-07-31 21:58:53 2024-08-01 02:58:53,201 INFO [-] Running sensor initialization code
2024-07-31 21:58:53 2024-08-01 02:58:53,201 INFO [-] Running sensor in passive mode
2024-07-31 21:58:53 2024-08-01 02:58:53,201 INFO [-] Polling...
2024-07-31 21:58:53 2024-08-01 02:58:53,231 INFO [-] Adding watch on dir [/appl/appcloud] for file [.*\\.txt]
2024-07-31 21:58:53 2024-08-01 02:58:53,237 INFO [-] Connected to amqp://guest:**@rabbitmq:5672//
2024-07-31 21:58:55 2024-08-01 02:58:55,204 INFO [-] Polling...
2024-07-31 21:58:55 2024-08-01 02:58:55,205 INFO [-] Starting observer with 1 watches

For what it's worth, removing one sleep or the other (eventlet or time) doesn't seem to make a difference. With both removed, it's just a busy-wait loop that just spins up CPU time, and still doesn't register file events.
